# Where do you end up?

Tags: riddle, visual, mazes

Do not only post your answer, but also your complete step-by-step solution

***Your start is, where the programming world has its origin


70:55:4E:61:69:6E:45:6E ͢ 


sinonimo: servilo estas senkonekta, servilo estas ... #0f0


123 145 145 040 155 145 040 151 156 040 163 165 155 155 145 162 054 040 111 040 153 145 145 160 040 142 151 162 144 163 054 040 145 166 145 156 040 157 165 164 040 157 146 040 163 164 145 145 154 054 040 167 150 141 164 040 151 163 040 155 171 040 143 157 154 157 162 077 040 111 040 141 155 040 141 154 163 157 040 164 150 145 040 144 151 162 145 143 164 151 157 156***

> **Map**
>
> [image: Map]
>
> **Map Large**
>
> [image: Map Large]

*Hint 1:*

> All the riddles/clues should give you "directions"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I think I got it

Here's what I got from the clues:

### The "start"

> I'm guessing we are talking about the "origin" as denoted in math, so I'm going to start my path here at what I believe to be (0,0) on the map. And that, to me, is the **top left** because we see the numbers on the right side increase as they go down, indicative of 0 being above them, and I doubt we are starting at the right side with the numbers because they seem to be the possible destinations.

### Clue 1

> "70:55:4E:61:69:6E:45:6E" converted from hex to text is **pUNainEn**, which is "red" in Finnish (thanks Google Translate). I take it the ͢ symbol means going to the right. So we start with **red right**.

### Clue 2

> "sinonimo: servilo estas senkonekta, servilo estas ... #0f0" is Esperanto that translates to "Synonymous: server is offline, server is **DOWN** #0f0." And #0f0 is the RGB value for green. So this clue means that the next direction is **green down**.

### Clue 3

> All those numbers are octal, and when converted to tex, say the following: *"See me in summer, I keep birds, even out of steel, what is my color? I am also the direction."* I believe this is talking about the sky. You see a lot of the sky in summer, and it is home to birds, as well as airplanes, which are "birds" (made) out of steel. The sky is **blue** and is **up** above our heads. This clue means **blue up**.

### Now what?

Looking at the map with our directionss, we can make the following route (apologies for no image; it's late for me):

> Start at top left, and voila! We have a red to start with. Go right from the red using our directions and we run into a green. Go down from there and we run into another red. Go right again and hit a second green, which leads us down to a third red. Go right and hit the blue. Go up and hit the red at the top-middle of the map. Go right (through the yellow because we didn't get a direction for it) and hit the green at the top near the 1. Go down, hit the red, and turn right. We have arrived at the number 1 space.

---

So my answer is

> You end up at **spot 1** in the map.

Comment: Ok, you are kind of on the right track, but also on the wrong one because you didn't interpret some clues correctly... Interesring ideas though

Comment: Ok I now realize how I screwed up clue 2... will edit my answer. Now I have to figure out clue 3 for real, because I definitely rushed that one.

Comment: Think I got it for real this time. Let me know if I did lol

Comment: The start ist correct even though I meant the coordinate system in a window (program) which has its origin (0|0) on the top left... But still, your answer is correct!